# Ubuntu20.04 and win10,The HDMI dont have output on win10

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi

My desktop is thinkpad X390 yoga,use Ubuntu 20.04 and Win10.When I shut down the Ubuntu and log in Win10,the monitor on HDMI dont have signal,and when I unplug the HDMI connector and plug it in again,it works normally.So how can I do to avoid to unplug and plug again when I log in Windows after Ubuntu.Thanks!

Comment: Not an Ubuntu problem. Why are you asking here?

Comment: Does it make a difference if you reboot or power-off/power-on when going from Ubuntu to Windows ?

Comment: The problem orrers when going Ubuntu to Win ,and not occer when going Win to Ubuntu.

Comment: When I only use Win10 ,it doesnt have any problem. Do you think is not an Ubuntu problem?